# How to remove multiple values from an array at once

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Can someone provide me with a better (simpler, more readable, more Pythonic, more efficient, etc.) way to remove multiple values from an array than what follows:

```
import numpy as np

# The array.
x = np.linspace(0, 360, 37)

# The values to be removed.
a = 0
b = 180
c = 360

new_array = np.delete(x, np.where(np.logical_or(np.logical_or(x == a,
                                                              x == b),
                                                x == c)))
```

A good answer to this question would produce the same result as the above code (i.e., `new_array`), but might do a better job dealing with equality between floats than the above code does.

## BONUS

Can someone explain to me why this produces the wrong result?

```
In [5]: np.delete(x, x == a)
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py:3254: FutureWarning: in the future insert will treat boolean arrays and array-likes as boolean index instead of casting it to integer
  "of casting it to integer", FutureWarning)
Out[5]: 
array([  20.,   30.,   40.,   50.,   60.,   70.,   80.,   90.,  100.,
        110.,  120.,  130.,  140.,  150.,  160.,  170.,  180.,  190.,
        200.,  210.,  220.,  230.,  240.,  250.,  260.,  270.,  280.,
        290.,  300.,  310.,  320.,  330.,  340.,  350.,  360.])
```

The values 0 and 10 have both been removed, rather than just 0 (`a`).

Note, `x == a` is as expected (so the problem is inside `np.delete`):

```
In [6]: x == a
Out[6]: 
array([ True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False], dtype=bool)
```

Note as well that `np.delete(x, np.where(x == a))` produces the correct result.  Thus, it appears to me that `np.delete` cannot handle Boolean indices.

Comment: If you have Boolean indices you don't need to use `delete`.  It specifies that  `obj : slice, int or array of ints` (no boolean).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code does seem a little complex. I wondered whether you had considered numpy's Boolean vector indexing.

After the same setup as you I timed your code:

```
In [175]: %%timeit
   .....: np.delete(x, np.where(np.logical_or(np.logical_or(x == a, x == b), x == c)))
   .....:
10000 loops, best of 3: 32.9 µs per loop
```

I then timed two separate applications of Boolean indexing.

```
In [176]: %%timeit
   .....: x1 = x[x != a]
   .....: x2 = x1[x1 != b]
   .....: new_array = x2[x2 != c]
   .....:
100000 loops, best of 3: 6.56 µs per loop
```

Finally, for programming convenience and to extend the technique to an arbitrary number of excluded values I rewrote the same code as a loop. This will be a little slower, because of the need to make a copy first, but it's still quite respectable.

```
In [177]: %%timeit
   .....: new_array = x.copy()
   .....: for val in (a, b, c):
   .....:     new_array = new_array[new_array != val]
   .....:
100000 loops, best of 3: 7.61 µs per loop
```

I think the real gain is in programming clarity, though. Finally I thought it best to verify that the three algorithms *were* giving the same results ...

```
In [179]: new_array1 = np.delete(x,
   .....:                 np.where(np.logical_or(np.logical_or(x == a, x == b), x == c)))

In [180]: x1 = x[x != a]

In [181]: x2 = x1[x1 != b]

In [182]: new_array2 = x2[x2 != c]

In [183]: new_array3 = x.copy()

In [184]: for val in (a, b, c):
   .....:         new_array3 = new_array3[new_array3 != val]
   .....:

In [185]: all(new_array1 == new_array2)
Out[185]: True

In [186]: all(new_array1 == new_array3)
Out[186]: True
```

To handle the issue of floating-point comparisons you need to use numpy's [`isclose()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html#numpy.isclose) function. As expected, this sends the timing to hell:

```
In [188]: %%timeit
   .....: new_array = x.copy()
   .....: for val in (a, b, c):
   .....:     new_array = new_array[~np.isclose(new_array, val)]
   .....:
10000 loops, best of 3: 126 µs per loop
```

The answer to your bonus is contained within the warning, but the warning isn't very useful unless you know that `False` and `True` compare numerically equal to zero and one respectively. So your code is equivalent to

```
np.delete(1, 1)
```

As the warning makes clear, the numpy team eventually intend that the result using Boolean arguments to `np.delete()` is likely to change, but at present it only takes index arguments.

Comment: yikes, the floating-point comparison fix comes with a big speed cost.

Comment: re: the warning, thanks for explaining that.  the warning says "insert" when it means "delete" -- that threw me.

Comment: Yes, the F-P comparisons cost a lot because instead of `x == y` the function has to compute `x-delta <= y <= x+delta`, a significantly more complex calculation. I reported the issue about the error message - this is the [bug report](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/5945).

Answer (score 7):

You can also use `np.ravel` to get index of `values` and then remove them using  `np.delete`

```
In [32]: r =  [a,b,c]

In [33]: indx = np.ravel([np.where(x == i) for i in r])

In [34]: indx
Out[34]: array([ 0, 18, 36])

In [35]: np.delete(x, indx)
Out[35]: 
array([  10.,   20.,   30.,   40.,   50.,   60.,   70.,   80.,   90.,
        100.,  110.,  120.,  130.,  140.,  150.,  160.,  170.,  190.,
        200.,  210.,  220.,  230.,  240.,  250.,  260.,  270.,  280.,
        290.,  300.,  310.,  320.,  330.,  340.,  350.])
```

Comment: this wins for readability.  i guess i'll wait a bit to see whether more answers come in and then do a speed test.

Comment: ah, hell, someone else can do the speed test.  for now, you're the winner.

Comment: It does seem to be reasonably fast as well. Nice answer!

Answer (score 2):

You could borrow `np.allclose` approach to testing whether floats are equal:

```
def float_equal(x,y,rtol=1.e-5, atol=1.e-8):
   return np.less_equal(abs(x-y), atol + rtol * abs(y))

np.delete(x,np.where(np.logical_or.reduce([float_equal(x,y) for y in [0,180,360]])))
```

There `where` part produces:

```
(array([ 0, 18, 36]),)
```

`float_equal` could probably be changed to broadcast `x` against `y`, eliminating the list comprehension.

I used the fact that `logical_or` is a `ufunc`, and has a `reduce` method.

You don't need the `where`; just use the result of the `logical_or` as a boolean index:

```
I = np.logical_or.reduce([float_equal(x,y) for y in [0,180,360]])
x[~I]
```

(with this small example, the direct use of the boolean is 2x faster than the `np.delete(np.where(...))` approach.)

---

With this `x`, `==` produces the same thing:

```
np.where(np.logical_or.reduce([x==y for y in [0,180,360]]))
# (array([ 0, 18, 36]),)
```

so does this vectorized approach:

```
abc = np.array([0,180,360])
np.where(np.sum(x==abc[:,None],axis=0))
# (array([ 0, 18, 36]),)
```

`x==abc[:,None]` is `(3,37)` boolean array; `np.sum` acts like a logical or.

My `float_equal` also works this way:

```
float_equal(x,abc[:,None]).sum(axis=0)
```

Comment: `np.delete(x,np.where(x==a))` behaves.  `x==a` is the wrong kind of input for `delete`.

Comment: ah, i see -- you're not using Boolean indices in your calls to `np.delete`.  i misread your answer earlier.